# PostgreSQL C Extensions without -Wdeclaration-after-statement

Tags: c, postgresql, makefile, postgresql-extensions

Currently, when I compile my extension I get,

```
warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   57 |  uint32 n = fctx->n;
```

PostgreSQL currently uses `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` during compilation. They set this option specifically in their `pgxs` global make file on my machine that's at,

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/lib/pgxs/src/Makefile.global
```

It is set with their `CFLAGS`,

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

Is there anyway to disable `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` or does every PostgreSQL extension author have to adopt this same convention? Can I override CFLAGS in my extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to squelch these warnings by ending my extension's `Makefile` like,

```
PG_CFLAGS += $(PERMIT_DECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT)
include $(PGXS)
```

---

RhodiumToad provided an alternative way after `include $(PGXS)`

```
include $(PGXS)
$(OBJS): CFLAGS += $(PERMIT_DECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT)
```

Thanks goes out RhodiumToad on `ircs://irc.libera.chat:6697/#postgresql`, he goes on to say

> configure tests whether `-Wno-declaration-after-statement` works and sets up that variable accordingly well actually I think it checks for `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` and if that works, assumes -Wno-... works too you can **put that rule after including `$(PGXS)`**, so you can make it conditional on `$(MAJORVERSION)` if need be or conditional on `PERMIT_DECLARATION_AFTER_STATEMENT` being defined

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can override it by the instructions described in the [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/extend-pgxs.html)

The variable `PG_CFLAGS` will be appended to `CFLAGS`, so just add `-Wno-declaration-after-statement`