# Is the GCC option -Wdeclaration-after-statement purely stylistic?

Tags: c, gcc, c89

Is the option `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` stylistic only? By that I mean, if I macro'd all cases in my C code where a variable was defined and I initialized them in them in the same fashion migrating from this older style C90 to the newer C99 style, would that code be byte-for-byte the same?

Here is how the option `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` is documented (from `man gcc`):

> Warn when a declaration is found after a statement in a block.  This construct, known from C++, was introduced with ISO C99 and is by default allowed in GCC. It is not supported by ISO C90.

And it allows you to take code like

```
int a;
{
    a = 42;
    printf( "%d", a );
}
```

and turn it into

```c
int a = 42;
printf( "%d", a );
```

---

This is a [follow-up to my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69764257/124486).

Comment: No, it's not purely stylistic.  If you're writing code that must also build on C90 compilers, you would want to be warned when you write code that those other compilers will not support.

Comment: @NateEldredge Updated to clarity -- that's not what I meant. I also self-answered this below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, it's not. For example, the above two snippets will compile byte-for-byte the same. So will the `foo` and `bar` below, **but `baz` will not**. Here is a [link to GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAJlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQgAMwAnKQADqgKhLYMzm4e3onJqQIBQaEsEVFxFphWNgJCBEzEBBnunlzllWk1dQQFIeGRegq19Y1ZLQOd3UUlEgCUFqiuxMjsHABuqHjoANT8qJsQ05sApADsAEKHGgCCmzebgQSbTIfR51e3R2cX1%2B%2B3eFR7my4mwOJ1e3x%2BPyYR2iABFNpIvM8wRCIQliPcqBAjl5EV4AKzoQ440iPYFIr4oj4wikoipKD7Iym3KHPOEI8lvJk3NEYrFE3EE/kkqHTDngn4namcm6Sr6yq5fNYbTZhOp7EGfaV3QSk1nwxEvGkyzXi95/AFAjWMrk8wSY7ECwnE0miw1a97y023OmYBlGpm2gj2/lEwXOkViymej3HKWXT2K9ZbVUAL3Vfq190ekduoP9Zv%2BWOIhnQ%2B2h2E2GmBGa9EJZsP1OZt6LtfJxoadPhdTYlsfz3to9Lz7pR9bZButAZbQbbjqF3bdtap/oTsY4s1onDxvE8HC0pFQnEcmwU80WvqJ0R4pAImnXswA1iA8Rp9JxJDu7wfOLwFCBX7ee7rqQcCwEgaAsAkdCROQlAQVB9BRMgwBcFwPg0LQBCRH%2BEBhF%2BYSBHUACenDXhBbCCAA8gwtAkUBpBYCwhjAOI9H4MQmDWHgKyYH%2B9GYKonGuFhpG8PcFRfrQeBhMWxBEc4WBfgQ6IsKJsxUAYwAKAAangmAAO6UQkjCiTIggiGI7BSGZ8hKGoX66C0BhGCApjGOYUlhH%2BkCzKgCRVAwfG/hUnEBfYDBOC4TR6P4gQ9MUfQtEkKQBcMzQ5ClaQTL0USjCFXHVIMDRRSMrShe0RXZQluUWEVaX9JVcWTIlsyngsSx6MpmDLDwG5bp%2B9GHhwqgABwAGwALRjZImzAMgyCAlwAB0Xh7I4JK4IQJDYleJLOJB0HEDtXDTLwgFaNMswIJgTBYFE%2BykE%2BL5vhwH6kLu%2B5Db%2B/43nel0vV4A2fT%2Bv1Af9PHECkdiSEAA%3D%3D%3D). **This demonstrates that hoisting the initialization to the declaration may NOT produce the same code**

```
void foo () {
    int a;
    {
        if ( 1 ) {
            a = 42;
            printf( "%d", a );
        }
        else {
            a = 42;
            printf( "%d", a );
        }
    }
}

void bar () {
    int a = 42;
    {
        if ( 1 ) {
            printf( "%d", a );
        }
        else {
            printf( "%d", a );
        }
    }
}

void baz () {
    int a;
    {
        if ( rand() > 0 ) {
            a = 42;
            printf( "%d", a );
        }
        else {
            a = 42;
            printf( "%d", a );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have misunderstood what this warning does. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Lundin It's my question. It does. This shows me that I can not macro-fix code written to under `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` and then remove `-Wdeclaration-after-statement`.

Comment: No it doesn't because this code has absolutely nothing to do with the warning and neither has the code in the question. See my posted answer. Also for some reason my comment showing the correct Godbolt code has been deleted.

Comment: @Lundin My question isn't how to solve the warning. I know what the warning is. I wanted to know whether or not I could disable the warning **AND AUTOMATICALLY** migrate the code base to the modern C convention of having declarations with initialization. The answer to that is that there can be a difference in compiled output, that is the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: These examples here prove nothing since they show no difference. Your golbolt example is irrelevant since it is showing non-optimized code. If you actually compile correctly https://godbolt.org/z/qWYWvznMn then literally the only difference between the three versions is the call to `rand()`, which you have sequenced after the variable assignment. In none of the versions the branch is present in the machine code and in all versions the variable is stored in a register `mov     esi, 42`.

Comment: Why do you think I care about optimized code to begin with? I didn't ask what an optimizer can do.

Comment: Because it is pointless to discuss differences in machine code between non-optimized code examples. Only differences in the actual release build should matter. For example, the PostgresSQL in your other question which supposedly brought all of this up to begin with _is_ using optimizations.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Would you like to argue about this some more in my comments? _For example, the PostgresSQL in your other question which supposedly brought all of this up to begin with is using optimizations_ but the optimizations there are irrelevant too.

Comment: Basically, if you wish to prove that it takes the different time for you and your neighbour to walk to the same store, you can't clock one example where you walk from your house then take a long detour in the woods, and then compare it with another example where you went straight from the neighbours house to the store. And then when someone points out that it doesn't make sense, you yell "why do you think I care about measuring the direct route!"

Comment: Because I keep telling you **that's not the question**. The question you want to ask is not the one I am asking. So step back and reset. I'm not asking a performance question **AT ALL** here. This isn't about performance. This is merely about whether or not you _can_ rewrite code from a C90 to C99 conventions and obtain binary compatibility, (this question was over fixing a convention in a legacy code base, the other question was over working around it). In the presence of branching you can not automatically upgrade conventions (end of story). It wasn't evident to me until I ran tests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238759/discussion-between-evan-carroll-and-lundin).

Comment: I updated my answer with corrected examples that you can try with and without optimizations enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I may be confused here, but I think that we are missing something.

Prior to C99, all variable declarations had to occur *before* any statements in a block. It did not matter where you assigned it a value (except maybe in generated assembly code).

```
int a;
do_something();
a = 7;
do_something_else();
```

What you *could not do* in C but has always been perfectly legal in C++ is mix declarations and statements:

```
do_something();
int a = 7;
do_something_else();
```

With the advent of C99 you can now do the same thing in C as you can in C++, and declare a variable anywhere in a block, even after non-declaration statements.

Ultimately it was a design decision based on making it easier to write a compiler that leaked into the language specification. Compilers are a little more sophisticated now (and much larger).

Comment: the question is, if in your above example you macroed the code such that **all** declarations which occur before statements in the block are joined by their initializers which occur below them in C90 would the code compile the same. And the answer seems to be no that it won't and it's not possible to rewrite code that violates `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` in a fashion where variables are declared and initialized together.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is correct, because it would break the compiler’s ability to reason about and generate code that is guaranteed to work the same in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Statement in this context either refers to a full expression ending with `;` or alternatively a *compound statement*, `{ }`. These terms are taken from the formal C grammar.

Declaration ***after*** statement does not apply to the code in your question. Because... you placed the declaration ***before*** a (compound) statement. Your two examples have nothing to do with this gcc setting, so it would appear that you have misunderstood what it does.

Rather, the relevant example would be:

```
{
    int a = 42;
}
```

versus

```
{
  puts("hello");
  int a = 42;
}
```

The former example is fine in any C version. The latter is fine in standard C, but not in the deprecated C90 standard. So the only purpose of the warning nowadays would be to give a diagnostic message for standard C programs where a certain coding style is enforced.

The vast majority of programmers out there should not use this warning and stick to standard C as defined in ISO 9899:2018.

---

EDIT:

> This is merely about whether or not you can rewrite code from a C90 to C99 conventions and obtain binary compatibility

Yes you can rewrite to C99 style without any consequences. None of these affect how the variable is treated in the "abstract machine" as C calls it. Here are some examples, 2 relevant and 1 irrelevant:

```
void relevant_c99_example (void) {
    if ( 1 ) {
        int a = 42;
        printf( "%d", a );
    }
    else {
        int a = 42;
        printf( "%d", a );
    }
}

void relevant_c90_example (void) {
    int a = 42;
    if ( 1 ) {
        printf( "%d", a );
    }
    else {
        printf( "%d", a );
    }
}

void irrelevant_example (void) {
    int a;
    if ( 1 ) {
        a = 42;
        printf( "%d", a );
    }
    else {
        a = 42;
        printf( "%d", a );
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1oqvoesx7

These 3 produce 100% identical machine code when tested on both gcc *and* clang for x86_64. They even produce 100% identical machine code when optimizations are disabled! Which one shouldn't expect, since that isn't how you benchmark C code correctly. But it happens to be the case here.